# ! Font EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not loadab le: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: beamer, fonts, miktex

I have this sample code that I was trying to run but it kept on producing an error that says:

```
! Font \zf@basefont=Flama-Light at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
! Font \@tempfonta=Flama-Light at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
! Font \@tempfontb=Flama-Light at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
! Font EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}

\usetheme{hsrm}
\usecolortheme[named=BurntOrange]
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove navigation symbols
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\title{A Discussion of rational and Psychological Decision-Making Theories and Models:}
\subtitle{The Search for a Cultural-Ethical Decision-Making Model}
\author[Arnaldo Oliveira]
\date{September 4, 2013}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{block}{Example}
      This is my first Beamer example.
   \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{Rational Decision-Making Models}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{block}{Example}
      This is my first Beamer example.
   \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{Psychological Decision-Making Models}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{block}{Example}
      This is my first Beamer example.
   \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've searched for answers in this website and found some similar problems and followed their answers but I still end up with the same errors. The code produced a PDF file but nothing is written on the slides.

Comment: it is likely that the "flama" font doesn't have latex font support (pdflatex requires a `.tfm` file for each font).  if this is a system font, you should be using xelatex.  check other questions for the proper use of `fontenc` and `inputenc` for that approach -- it's different from what's used with pdflatex.

Comment: I don't see where the font is loaded, but then I don't recognise a `hsrm` theme for `beamer`: is this a local custom one?

Comment: Ah, I've found https://github.com/hsrmbeamertheme/hsrmbeamertheme/blob/master/beamerthemehsrm.sty. Looking over the code, it relies on `fontspec` being available, so XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, and presumably you having access to the font. Do you have a copy of [Flama](http://www.felicianotypefoundry.com/cms/fonts/flama)? It seems to be a commercial font.

Comment: Oh now i get it. I don't have a copy of Flama @joseph and I'm not using xelatek either. Maybe i should just change my beamer theme since I'm short with time fixing the error anyways.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone was drawn here, like me, by the tantalizing presence of the error message:

```
! Font EU1/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

My problem was that I needed to `sudo apt-get install fonts-lmodern`.

Comment: Great, thanks, that was also my problem on a debian!

Comment: On Manjaro, `texlive-fontsrecommended` is what I needed (more specifically may have been `texlive-lm`, but I usually prefer not to cherry-pick Tex font packages).

Answer (score 3):

I have succesfully used Beamer HSRM theme without 'flama' installed in Ubuntu 14 with 'xelatex', I just used an option I saw in the .sty file, this way:

```
\usetheme[noflama]{hsrm}
```

I also had to install micrsoft fonts in my Ubuntu 14 machine, because the 'noflama' option makes use of 'Arial' font instead of 'Flama'. (I installed them with these instructions: http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/09/installing-microsoft-fonts/, I think I had used hsrm without doing this in previous Ubuntu versions)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds as if your theme should be used with xelatex. In this case don't load inputenc!

Answer (score 2):

The `beamer` theme [`hsrm`](https://github.com/hsrmbeamertheme/hsrmbeamertheme/) is clearly very much tied to the requirements of a particular university. In particular, it requires the [Flama](http://www.felicianotypefoundry.com/cms/fonts/flama) font, which is commercial and is assumed to be installed locally. It also requires the use of XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX as a result. If you do have the font, use one of these engines and drop `inputenc` from your source. If you don't have the font you'll have to extract what you want/need from the theme by hand, at least dropping the font part.