# fontspec error with lualatex MiKTeX

Tags: luatex, miktex, fontspec, luaotfload

When compiling MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I get the error message (part of it)

```
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for EU2+lmr on input line 105.
("C:/Users/vaamat/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmr.fd"
File: eu2lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern)
! Font \EU2/lmr/m/n/10=file:lmroman10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
```

Any help how to fix?

This question is related to [fontspec throwing error with lualatex - broken?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161595/fontspec-throwing-error-with-lualatex-broken). However, I am using MiKTeX and that question is about TeX Live.

System: Win7 and 64 bit MiKTeX install (my system is 64 bit).

I have tried

- uninstalling MiKTeX throughly and reinstalling
- `luaotfload-tool --update` (does not work with MiKTeX)
- `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: You are ignoring an earlier error, something like ` Luaotfload requires a Luatex version >= 0.95.0.`.  With miktex you must install a luaotfload prerelease: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/387

Comment: This works. My text Editor (Texmaker 1.9.9) did not show me this error at all; the first error it gave me is the one I reported.

Comment: Don't rely on editors to report all errors, always check the log-file and try to compile on a command line.

Answer (score 1):

Radon Rosborough's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360733/134574) worked for me.

I used `sudo apt-get install fonts-lmodern` to install the missing files.