# Compilation error using fontspec to set Calibri as a main font with TexStudio and LuaLatex on Windows

Tags: luatex, miktex, fontspec

I have been working for some time on a document that uses the calibri font for the main text. However, recently I updated my packages through MiKTeX and now, using `LuaLaTeX` as my main compiler, the document no longer renders. I am sure it is some setting within Windows or TexStudio but I have been unable to figure it out. If I type this simple document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}
here is some text
\end{document}
```

Then I get the error exited with errors file and a blank `pdf`. The error `log` being

[image: Error log]

I have tried multiple things, from installing packages that supposedly resolve these errors to trying `XeLaTeX` as a different compiler. But so far none of the solutions have worked. And all that I get, when using it on my main document, is images and a huge log file. The only way to resolve, so far, the error is to remove the `fontspec` package.

Comment: You probably need the luaotfload Prerelease http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342992/fontspec-error-with-lualatex-miktex

Comment: Using the instructions by https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/387 worked for me, thanks.